# How to assign the N, Log-likelihood, AIC, and BIC values to each of multivariate regression models in a merged `gtsummary` table output?

Tags: r, gtsummary

Please, how do I assign the N, Log-likelihood, AIC, and BIC values to each of the multivariate regression models in a merged `gtsummary` table output?

I am a *Rmerteur* trying to fit additive multivariate models adding higher-level variables to subsequent models (see below example). Meanwhile, I could not retain the N, Log-likelihood, AIC, and BIC values for each model fit once I merge the separate models. I need the estimates to compare the fit across the models.

Is there an easy way to get this done?

Thank you for your help!

```
m1<-
  tbl_regression(mod1,
    exponentiate = T, hide_n = T, 
    add_estimate_to_reference_rows = T,
    estimate_fun = ~style_ratio(.x, digits = 2), 
    pvalue_fun = ~style_pvalue(.x, digits = 2), 
    label = list(age_yr_grp ~ "Age",
                 educ ~ "Education")) %>%
  bold_p(t = 0.05) %>% 
  add_glance_source_note()  

m2<-
  tbl_regression(mod2,
    exponentiate = T, hide_n = T, 
    add_estimate_to_reference_rows = T,
    estimate_fun = ~style_ratio(.x, digits = 2), 
    pvalue_fun = ~style_pvalue(.x, digits = 2), 
    label = list(age_yr_grp ~ "Age",
                 educ ~ "Education",
                 hhwealth ~ "Household wealth",
                 hhsize ~ "Household size")) %>%
  bold_p(t = 0.05) %>% 
  add_glance_source_note()  

m3<-
  tbl_regression(mod3,
    exponentiate = T, hide_n = T, 
    add_estimate_to_reference_rows = T,
    estimate_fun = ~style_ratio(.x, digits = 2), 
    pvalue_fun = ~style_pvalue(.x, digits = 2), 
    label = list(age_yr_grp ~ "Age",
                 educ ~ "Education",
                 hhwealth ~ "Household wealth",
                 hhsize ~ "Household size",
                 placeres~ "Area of residence")) %>%
  bold_p(t = 0.05) %>% 
  add_glance_source_note()     


tab3_multivars_models= 
  tbl_merge(list(m1,m2,m3),
  tab_spanner= c("**Mod 1**","**Mod 2**","**Mod 3**"))%>%
  as_gt() %>%
  tab_header(title = "Table title here") %>%
  tab_source_note(gt::md("*Notes here"))

gt::gtsave(tab3_multivars_models, "dir\\tab3_multivars_models.html", inline_css = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use `add_glance_table()` instead of the source note version.

```r
library(gtsummary)
#> #Uighur
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.4.0'

tbl1 <-
  lm(age ~ marker + grade, trial) %>% 
  tbl_regression() %>%
  add_glance_table(
    label = list(sigma ~ "\U03C3"),
    include = c(r.squared, AIC, sigma)
  )

tbl2 <- tbl_merge(list(tbl1, tbl1))
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-04-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Worked like magic!!!! Thank you very much. @Daniel D. Sjoberg